# grep with python subprocess replacement

Tags: python, subprocess, sh

On a switch, i run `ntpq -nc rv` and get an output:

> associd=0 status=0715 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, clock_sync,
>   version="ntpd 4.2.6p3-RC10@1.2239-o Mon Mar 21 02:53:48 UTC 2016 (1)",
>   processor="x86_64", system="Linux/3.4.43.Ar-3052562.4155M", leap=00,
>   stratum=2, precision=-21, rootdelay=23.062, rootdisp=46.473,
>   refid=17.253.24.125,
>   reftime=dbf98d39.76cf93ad  Mon, Dec 12 2016 20:55:21.464,
>   clock=dbf9943.026ea63c  Mon, Dec 12 2016 21:28:03.009, peer=43497,
>   tc=10, mintc=3, offset=-0.114, frequency=27.326, sys_jitter=0.151,
>   clk_jitter=0.162, clk_wander=0.028

I am attempting to create a bash shell command using Python's subprocess module to extract only the value for "offset", or `-0.114` in the example above

I noticed that I can use the subprocess replacement mod or sh for this such that:

```
import sh

print(sh.grep(sh.ntpq("-nc rv"), 'offset'))
```

and I get:

```
mintc=3, offset=-0.114, frequency=27.326, sys_jitter=0.151,
```

which is incorrect as I just want the value for 'offset', -0.114.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, whether its my grep function or I am not using the sh module correctly.

Comment: you might consider tagging this with python as it's nothing to do with shell or grep.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` reads line by line; it returns every line matching any part of the input. But I think `grep` is overkill. Once you get shell output, just search for the thing after `output`:

```
items = sh.ntpq("-nc rv").split(',')
for pair in items:
    name, value = pair.split('=')
    # strip because we weren't careful with whitespace
    if name.strip() == 'offset':
        print(value.strip())
```